# Strange behavior laravel 6.2 collections on php 7.4

Tags: php, laravel

I recently updated updated my version of `php` `7.3` to `7.4` and i noticed a strange behavior on `Laravel` version `6.*` collections. The following piece of code works:

```
    $modules = Module::orderByPriority()->get()->transform(function($module){

        dd(['id'=>$module->id, 'name'=>$module->course->name.' - '. $module->name]);
    });
```

And this don't work:

```
    $modules = Module::orderByPriority()->get()->transform(function($module){

         return ['id'=>$module->id, 'name'=>$module->course->name.'-'. $module->name];
    });
```

returning always the given error:
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dd()` stops the iteration at the first iteration of the `transform()` method. Most likely, you have a module that does not have a course, hence during its iteration, you get an error because `$module->course` is null, hence trying to access `name` property on null gives you the error

Comment: @LipeTuga as a side note, you should eager load your relationships using `->with('course')` or `->load('course')` to avoid [n+1 queries](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-n-1-problem)